# Function to pass javascript variables to a php file via a GET or POST?

Tags: php, javascript

I've got the following function

`function make(point, name, message, type, file, id, lat, lng)`

I want this function to pass all of these Javascript variables to a php file which would open in a window when a link is pressed how would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.open('path/to/php?point=' + point + '&name=' + name); // etc for all other vars
```

make sure the values of your variables are urlsafe, i'd urlencode them with:

```
encodeURIComponent(variable);
```

**Edit re your comment**

```
<a href="#" onclick="make(vars, go, here); return false;">Click me!</a>
```

but if thats all you want, you might as well just have the link open in a blank window:

```
<a href="path/to/php?point=foo&etc=bar" target="_blank">Click me!</a>
```

It depends if `make()` is doing something else other than opening a window, i suspect so?

Comment: How would I make this code only execute when a link is pressed?